# Python CSV writer creates new line for each data item

Tags: python, csv, newline

I'm running Python 3.9.2 on a Raspberry Pi and I've written a script that will read water temperatures from my boiler and write them to a CSV file. However, each data item in the output file appears on a new line.

Here's my code:

```
from subprocess import check_output
import csv
header = ['Flow', 'Return']
cmd = ["/usr/bin/ebusctl", "read", "-f"]
data = [
   [float(check_output([*cmd, "FlowTemp", "temp"]))],
   [float(check_output([*cmd, "ReturnTemp", "temp"]))]
]
with open('sandbox.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

And here's the content of sandbox.csv:

```
Flow,Return
57.19
43.12
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV files contain one *record* per row.

The `writerow` method writes one record to the file which it expects to be represented as one list or tuple *of values*, e.g. for one record `a, b, c`:

```
[a, b, c]
```

The `writerows` method does the same for multiple records at once, which it expects to be represented as a list or tuple *of records*, e.g. for two records `a, b, c` and `x, y, z`:

```
[[a, b, c], [x, y, z]]
```

The data you are passing to `writerows` is structured like this:

```
[[Flow], [Return]]
```

This means that `writerows` will write two records to the file (each in one line), each containing only one value.

If you intend `Flow, Return` to be *one* record (written to one line), your data needs to be structured differently:

- Either you create `data = [Flow, Return]` (a single record) and pass it to `writerow`.
- Or you create `data = [[Flow, Return]]` (a list of records, containing only one record) and pass it to `writerows`.

Comment: Thanks you for explaining that so clearly. I went with your first suggestion and it works now.